# Sorting of array by substrings

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to sort array by substrings and also input missing parts.

**Current version:**
“K1\SK1”

“K1\SK2”

“K1\SK1\SSK1”

“K1\SK1\SSK2”

“K2”

“K2\SK1\SSK1”

“K2\SK1\SSK2”

**Expected version:**

“K1”

“K1\SK1”

“K1\SK1\SSK1”

“K1\SK1\SSK2”

“K1\SK2”

“K2”

“K2\SK1”

“K2\SK1\SSK1”

“K2\SK1\SSK2”

I already have tried to split strings to arrays by("/") then to sort every part of array separately. But eventually it's too inconvenient and hard algoritm!

Maybe someone knows an easier way how to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I don't understand why the default sort on `String` would not work here. Can you tell a bit more of what you have as input?

Comment: What do you mean by "input the missing part"?

Comment: 1) Why would you want to split by ("/") when the text has ``\``, not ``/``? 2) Adding extra value means that you're not *sorting*. Sorting is the act of rearranging in a different order. Sorting doesn't add new values to the list.

Comment: @doctorlove OP means that e.g. `“K1”` is added to the list, derived from the paths that start with `K1\...`. Think of input as qualified file names, and OP wants to know what directories to create.

Comment: What about any reaction to given answers and marking one as accepted to let others see that the problem was successfully solved?

Comment: What about any reaction to given answers and marking one as accepted to let others see that the problem was successfully solved?

Answer (score 0):

You create a sorted `Set`, i.e. a `TreeSet<String>`, for storing the result.

You then iterate the input strings, and for each string you add it to the result `Set`. You also scan for all `\` characters, and for each `\` character found, you grab the substring from the beginning of the string, up to but not including the `\`, and add that to the result `Set`.

The `Set` now contains the result you're after. You can extract that as an array if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here Python code, not JAVA, but I think it will be easy to adapt this code to usage of sorted set as I wrote is as self-explanatory as I could:

```
def lstAllPositionsOfSeparatorCharInString(strSepChar, strToQuery): 
    """Return a list with all the positions of a character strSepChar in a string strToQuery."""
    lstPositions = []
    intPos = strToQuery.find(strSepChar)
    while intPos != -1: # strSepChar was found, proceed
        lstPositions.append(intPos)
        intPos = strToQuery.find(strSepChar, intPos+1)
    #:while
    return lstPositions
#:def

lstStrings=[r"K1\SK1", r"K1\SK2", r"K1\SK1\SSK1", r"K1\SK1\SSK2", r"K2", r"K2\SK1\SSK1", r"K2\SK1\SSK2"]
print(lstStrings)
# Append missing items if any: 
strSepChar = r"\ "[0] # strSepChar will contain a single backslash
for item in lstStrings: 
    for posNo in lstAllPositionsOfSeparatorCharInString(strSepChar, item):
        if item[0:posNo] not in lstStrings: 
            lstStrings.append(item[0:posNo])
#:for :for :if
print( lstStrings )
# sort the list (in place):
lstStrings.sort()
print( lstStrings )
```

The code gives as output first the original list, than the expanded list and finally the sorted list (set):

```
"""
'K1\\SK1', 'K1\\SK2', 'K1\\SK1\\SSK1', 'K1\\SK1\\SSK2', 'K2', 'K2\\SK1\\SSK1', 'K2\\SK1\\SSK2']
['K1\\SK1', 'K1\\SK2', 'K1\\SK1\\SSK1', 'K1\\SK1\\SSK2', 'K2', 'K2\\SK1\\SSK1', 'K2\\SK1\\SSK2', 'K1', 'K2\\SK1']
['K1', 'K1\\SK1', 'K1\\SK1\\SSK1', 'K1\\SK1\\SSK2', 'K1\\SK2', 'K2', 'K2\\SK1', 'K2\\SK1\\SSK1', 'K2\\SK1\\SSK2']
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, and you also need some import's.

```
     public class Sort {  
/**
 * Sort.
 * @param list original list
 */
public void sortByDirectOrder(List<String> list) {
    checkContainsAll(list);
    list.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int result;
            int length1 = o1.length();
            int length2 = o2.length();
            int length = length1 < length2 ? length1 : length2;
            int subResult = o1.substring(0, length).compareTo(o2.substring(0, length));
            if (subResult == 0) {
                 result = length1 < length2 ? -1 : length2 < length1 ? 1 : 0;
            } else {
                 result = subResult;
            }
            return result;
        }
        });      
    }

/**
 * Method for check and complement list of codes.
 * @param list original list
 */
private void checkContainsAll(List<String> list) {
    List<String> additionalList = new ArrayList<>();
    String substring;
    for (String code : list) {
        if (code.contains("\\")) {
            for (int index = 0; index != code.length(); index++) {
                index = code.indexOf("\\", index);
                if (index == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                substring = code.substring(0, index);
                if (!list.contains(substring) && !additionalList.contains(substring)) {
                    additionalList.add(substring);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (additionalList.size() > 0) {
        list.addAll(additionalList);
    }
}
}
```